# Post/Redirect/Get паттерн

Tags: java, servlet, redirect, шаблоны-проектирования

Хочу разобрать с использование паттерна PRG. Пытаюсь написать шаблон контроллера, который будет обрабатывать команды и возвращать jsp страницу используя PRG паттер. Но нет уверенности в правильности. Необходима конструктивная критика.

```
@WebServlet("/Controller")
public class Сontroller extends HttpServlet {

private boolean flag = false;
private String resultPage;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (flag == false){
      resultPage = //выполнение процесса
    }
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(resultPage);
    view.forward(request, response);
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resultPage = //выполнение процесса
    flag=true;
    response.sendRedirect("Controller");
}
```

}

Comment: Хотите конструктивную критику и доказательство правильности без человеческого вмешательства? **Напишите автоматический тест!** Люди не нужны! Слава роботам!

Comment: Сразу видно, что в многопоточной среде будут проблемы из-за хранения состояния в полях объекта.

Comment: Spring MVC (web) решает множество проблем...